# OneDrive for Business - Sync fails frequently

Tags: onedrive

I have oneDrive for Business configured in 2 of my machines which are in  different network domains. There are files which needs to be synced.
From my observation, the sync is not running 100% accurately.

On a daily basis, I am seeing sync failures for 3 to 4 times. When I Click on Syn Now option, I get sync problems and I get stuck there.

So I manually uninstall/resinstall OneDrive in some cases when I reach dead end.

Is there a way to force sync programmitically or resolve the sync issues. is there some patches available which I need to get from Microsoft?

Please do let me know and I appreciate your help.

Comment: OneDrive is really working very unstable.

Comment: Given OneDrive client is unstable, Is there a way to force upload through API. I am very confused as how to use the API. I dont have any apps. This is a simple file movement from my machine to the cloud.